# What is the difference between passing a block as an argument and passing a proc as a argument?

Tags: ruby, block, proc

We had to write a function that should accept an array, a proc, and a block as args. It should return the element from the array that has the largest result when passed into the block. If its a tie, it should should use the proc to break the tie.

The solution was as follows:

```
def max_tie_breaker(array, tie_breaker, &prc)
    return nil if array.empty?
    max = array.first
    array.each do |el|
        result_el = prc.call(el)
        result_max = prc.call(max)
        if result_el > result_max
            max = el
        elsif result_el == result_max && tie_breaker.call(el) > tie_breaker.call(max)
            max = el
        end
    end
    max
end
```

When testing the code, they did the following:

```
array_1 =['potato', 'swimming', 'cat'] 
array_2 = ['cat', 'bootcamp', 'swimming', 'ooooo']
array_3 = ['photo','bottle', 'bother'] 
length = Proc.new { |s| s.length } 
o_count = Proc.new { |s| s.count('o') }

        

print max_tie_breaker(array_1, o_count, &length)
#('swimming')
puts
print max_tie_breaker(array_2, length, &o_count)
#('ooooo')
puts
```

What I dont understand is if they are passing a block and a proc as arguments, then the block would show up as &prc in the method parameters, would be called by passing in a block when the method is called. For example to call max_tie_breaker, wouldn't you type:
max_tie_breaker(array_1, o_count) { |s| s.length } as opposed to max_tie_breaker(array_1, o_count, &length).  Basically, I am not understanding how they have a method that expects an array, a block, and a proc as an argument but calling it with an array and two procs and it still is working fine.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert by any means so others may correct me. The above behaviour you note is: due to ruby convention. When you have `&prc` this converts a block into a proc. But if you are passing a proc as a third argument, it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator tries to convert whatever follows into a block.

So when you call a method with `foo(a, &b)` the method doesn't receive 2 arguments, the method receives `a` as it's first and only argument and is also given a block.

Methods can call blocks by using the `yield` keyword or turn them into callable procs using the `&` operator again.

For example `def foo(a, &b)` can be called as `foo(a, &b)` or `foo(a) { "bar" }`. In both cases, inside the method `b` will be a proc that represents the given block.

Calling this method with 2 procs instead of a proc and a block would give an error.

```rb
def foo(a, &b)
end

foo(->{}, ->{}) # ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
foo(->{}, &->{}) # nil
foo(->{}) {} # nil
foo(->{}) do end # nil
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.